# How to get categories and sub categories sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to get all categories with all sub categories using this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    sections.Section_Name,
    sections.Section_Page,
    topics.Topic_Name,
    topics.Topic_Descr,
    topics.Section_ID,
    (select count(*) from threads WHERE threads.Topic_ID= topics.Topic_ID and threads.Topic_ID=topics.Topic_ID) as Thread,
    (select count(*) from threads join posts on posts.Thread_ID= threads.Thread_ID where threads.Topic_ID =topics.Topic_ID) as Post,
    **(SELECT Thread_Time 
       FROM
           (SELECT Thread_Time FROM threads
            WHERE threads.Topic_ID = Topic_ID 
            ORDER BY threads.Thread_ID Desc limit 1) AS Time) AS Time**
FROM 
    topics, sections 
WHERE 
    topics.Section_ID = sections.Section_ID
```

It works fine but the Thread_Time query shows the same date on all rows (records)?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Only tag with the database you are using.  Also learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using subqueries is fine for this query.  If you want the most recent time, then I think you can do:

```
select s.Section_Name, s.Section_Page,
       t.Topic_Name, t.Topic_Descr, t.Section_ID,
       (select count(*)
        from threads th 
        where th.Topic_ID = t.Topic_ID
       ) as Thread,
       (select count(*)
        from threads th join
             posts p
             on p.Thread_ID = th.Thread_ID
        where th.Topic_ID = t.Topic_ID
       ) as Post,
       (select max(th.Thread_Time)
        from threads th
        where th.Topic_ID = t.Topic_ID 
       )as Time
from topics t join
     sections s
     on t.Section_ID = s.Section_ID;
```

The problem with your query is this clause:  `threads.Topic_ID=Topic_ID`.  This is just referencing the value in the subquery.

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'th.t' in 'where clause'

Comment: @Kamal: There is no `th.t` in the query. You must have made a mistake. (Maybe you have inserted a blank, e.g. `where th.T opic_ID` instead of `where th.Topic_ID`).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . There was a typo, which I fixed a little while ago.